# How can I select an element by an attribute set on its parent using CSS 2.0 selectors?

Tags: css, qt, css-selectors, qwebview

I have a HTML like this in my [`QWebView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html)

```
<div class='a' id='root'>
<div id='x'>...</div>
<p> ...
<p>
...
<div id='x2'>...</div>
<div>
    <a href='go/xxxx'>go</a>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I select the `a`? I tried this selectores:

```
div[id='root'].a
div[id='root'] + a
```

but it didn't worked. Code:

```
QWebFrame* frame = webView->page()->mainFrame();
QWebElement button = frame->documentElement().findFirst("div[id='root'].a");
assert(!button.isNull()); // gets executed
```

Comment: i removed [tag:xpath] as it has nothing to do with it ;).

Comment: @Abel: Does Qt really only support legacy CSS 2.0 selectors, as implied by your edit on the question?

Comment: @BoltClock, no, [Qt even has (limited) support for XPath 2.0, XSLT 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 through xmlpatterns](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/xmlprocessing.html#xslt-2-0) set of libs, as one of very few C++ libraries. But the OP only uses classes and methods that use CSS 2.0 with QWebView, not the XML classes.

Comment: @BoltClock, sorry, thought it was about me removing the [tag:xpath]. Yes, Qt claims it [only supports (all of) CSS2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) and doesn't mention 2.1. It also says that their dialect is not true CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is selecting the div with id='root' and class='a'.  If you want to select the a tag inside of that div, you need to make your selector:

```
div[id='root'].a a
```

The additional 'a' at the end of the selector tells jquery to select the a inside of the div.

Comment: totally missed that requirement when writing my answer, spot on and +1

Comment: Worked fine, let's assume I want to make sure it's the `a` which contains `go` in the href attribute value, how will the query be like? something like this: `div[id=root] a[contains(@href, 'groups')]`?

Comment: I found it, just the `*=` operator act as `contains()` function

Comment: Yes, just to reiterate, it would look like this `div[id='root'] a[href*='go']`
Also, if the answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Jack: Does Qt really only support CSS2 selectors as implied by your question? Because if so, you wouldn't be able to use `*=`.

Comment: @BoltClock: I really don't know. I didn't put any specific css selector version; this was assumed and edited by the community.

Comment: @BoltClock, as in my comment under the OP, [Qt claims to only support CSS2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types). The `*=` is not mentioned. They support `::` from CSS3, but it works differently (see link).

Answer (score 1):

You can [switch to using XPath 2.0 in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/xmlprocessing.html#xpath-2-0) to have more expressive freedom, but then you need to process your HTML as XML.

To resolve, add a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors)<sup>1</sup> for `a`. I.e., change this `div[id='root'].a` into this:

```
div[id=root].a a
```

As an alternative, if there's a bug in Qt, try:

```
div[id=root][class=a] a
```

Or (which is potentially a bit wider):

```
div[id~=root][class~=a] a
```

These last two are just alternatives in case for some reason the original fix to your code (adding the `a` descendant selector) didn't work.

The code snippets above doesn't use quoted strings, this is optional.

<sup>1</sup> *adding `a` was seen in [stevenc4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32531931/111575)), after my original (wrong) solution. Kudos to him :)*